# Custom action on comment post

Tags: php, comments, actions

Whenever a user posts a comment, I'd like to basically have a copy of the post sent to another database for a separate site. The database part is simple, but I can't seem to find the right action hook for this. (I did my testing with a simple echo statement, a failure being it not displaying at all) 'comment_save_pre' would only work when updating a comment, 'wp_set_comment_status' only works when the comment is approved, and 'comment_post' didn't seem to work at all. Does the hook exist?

```
add_action('...?...', 'on_comment_post');

function on_comment_post($comment){
     echo "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`wp_insert_comment`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/comment.php#L1259) action, which is triggered on every comment insertion.